# SAMLAuthenticationProvider doesnot maintain the "details" information that is received in the Authentication object

Tags: spring-saml

Currently I am observing the following behaviour when using SAMLAUthenticationProvider. In the "authenticate" method, there is this line:
        ExpiringAuthenticationToken result = .... //Initializes this object here
        result.setDetails(userDetails);
The problem I am facing here is, if i had set a "details" object in the incoming Authentication object, then that information is not passed back to my application. But this is not the case with the other authentication providers like abstractldapprovider, abstractuserdetialsauthenticationprovider. In these providers, createsuccessfulauthentication() retains/copies the additional "details" information from the parent authentication object to the new authentication object.

Is there a way to achieve the same thing with the SAMLAuthenticationProvider too. Currently I can see "overriding" the whole authenticate method and call super.authenticate for all the saml processing and just change the setDetails line to be able to achieve this.

Please let me know if any better solution is available.

Answer (score 0):

Each Identity Provider has their own rule to pass back detail information for authenticated user.

For example, in SSOCircle, the attributes has to be set when you add a new Service Provider. Go to "Manage Matadata", and click on "Add new Service Provider ", and check the attributes you want to include in the assertion it sends back.
[image]